# Object inside inner html not getting identified by selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want to select and click on the object present inside inner html (shown in the image). But the object is not getting identified. I am using Java.

**Note** --> my application not opening with any browser except Internet Explorer and I can't verify xpath from console/debugger so I have to verify it through code only.

Code I have tried so far but not working for me-->

## option 1 -->

```
driver.switchTo().frame("nav");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a href[@text='Administrate']")).click();
```

## option 2 -->

```
driver.switchTo().frame("nav");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@text='Administrate']")).click();
```

## option 3 -->

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/frameset/frame[1]/html/body/ul/li/ul/li[1]")).click();
```

[image: I have pasted the html structure here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for exact text match, use `contains` instead

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Administrate')]")).click();
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Administrate')]")).click();
```

Please note the difference between `text()` and `@text`

Comment: seems object getting identified as not getting any exception ... but NOT able to click .. please help

Comment: Thnkx "Guy" Used Javascript for clicking and now able to click the link , But if you have some better idea please share ...

try{
 WebElement element = selActionKeywords.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Administrate system')]"));
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)selActionKeywords.driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println("Exceptio --> "+ e);
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your XPath like

```
driver.switchTo().frame("nav");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Administrate system']")).click();
```

Note:- Here you need to pass complete string for better learning please refer  [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) to create and evaluate your xpath

Also can use `contains` method to find an element on partial text basis

Comment: seems object getting identified as not getting any exception ... but NOT able to click .. please help

Comment: Is your link comes under website menu ? I think under `<ul>` tag `style="DISPLAY: block"` comming before `<li>`tag of your link is causing the problem.